# Passing value of a variable in findElement function in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

I want to know how can I pass a value that is given through a for function to the value parameter in findElement function of RSelenium package.

The code is the following:

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='mainContent_lbCcats']/option[@value='10']")
option$clickElement()
```

But instead I want the following, which does not work:

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='mainContent_lbCcats']/option[@value=var]")
option$clickElement()
```

How can I pass the value of a variable that changes through a loop in R?

Regards,

Comment: The value you pass is just a string. You can create whatever value you need in that string using whatever string building functions you like in R. It's unclear from your question exactly what you are trying to change or loop over here.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I'm trying to pass the value of a variable instead of the hardcoded value, but option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='mainContent_lbCcats']/option[@value=var]") does not work.

Comment: Well, what's the variable in that expression? You just have a literal string there.

Comment: Oh, is `var` supposed to be some variable? Like `var <- "10"`? Then you can just use `paste0` to build the string like you wouid any other string concatenation: `paste0("//select[@id='mainContent_lbCcats']/option[@value='", var, "']")`

Comment: Yes, that's was I was looking for! Many thanks!